# ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION error when mapping one entity within two others

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using the Entity Framework with the following classes

```
public class ContatoProfissional : Contato
{
    public GuidId ProfissionalId { get; set; }

    public virtual Profissional Profissional { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class ContatoPaciente : Contato
{
    public GuidId PacienteId { get; set; }

    public virtual Paciente Paciente { get; set; } = null!;
}

public abstract class Contato
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string? Telefone { get; set; }
}

public class Profissional
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ContatoProfissional? Contato { get; set; }
}

public class Paciente
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ContatoPaciente? Contato { get; set; }
}
```

With the following mapping

```
public class ProfissionalConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Profissional>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Profissional> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder
            .HasOne(x => x.Contato)
            .WithOne(x => x.Profissional)
            .HasForeignKey<ContatoProfissional>(x => x.ProfissionalId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
    }
}

public class PacienteConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Paciente>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Paciente> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder
            .HasOne(x => x.Contato)
            .WithOne(x => x.Paciente)
            .HasForeignKey<ContatoPaciente>(x => x.PacienteId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
    }
}

public class ContatoConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Contato>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contato> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

With this Classes/Mapping configuration or if you execute the `Update-Database` command the following error is generated:

> The introduction of the FOREIGN KEY restriction
> 'FK_Contact_Professional_ProfessionalId' in table 'Contact' can
> cause cycles or multiple cascading paths. Specify ON DELETE NO
> ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN restrictions
> KEY.

In this scenario "**Contato**" is an entity that only exists if it is linked to the parent entity (**Professional** and **Paciente**), and to create the link the classes "**ContatoProfessional** are used " and "**ContatoPaciente**" which have their respective **FKs** and **navigation property**.

SQL generated by migration:

```
CREATE TABLE [Contato] (
    [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [Telefone] nvarchar(20) NULL,
    [Discriminator] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    [PacienteId] uniqueidentifier NULL,
    [ProfissionalId] uniqueidentifier NULL,
    [DataCriacao] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [DataAlteracao] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] rowversion NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Contato] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Contato_Pacientes_PacienteId] FOREIGN KEY ([PacienteId]) REFERENCES [Pacientes] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Contato_Profissionais_ProfissionalId] FOREIGN KEY ([ProfissionalId]) REFERENCES [Profissionais] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

How to solve this problem? it is not possible to disable cascade delete globally and also the "**Contato**" does not make sense without the entity "**Parent (Profissional/Paciente)**"